# Jetty 9 HTTPclient: How to get the request content?

Tags: java, junit, jetty

I am using Jetty HTTP client to send request, in the bellow test case I want to test that the payload has been successfully added:
But I can't find how to get it from the Request [1]

Here is my method that I want to test:

```
public Request createRequest (HttpClient httpClient, String url,HTTP_METHOD http_method, HashMap <String, String> headers,String payload, HashMap <String, String> params){

    Request request;

    request = httpClient.newRequest(url);   
    request.method(getHttpMethod(http_method));

    /* add headers if any */
    if(headers!=null){      
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());                       
        }               
    }else{/*Nothing to do*/}

    /* add params if any */
    if(params!=null){       
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            request.param(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());                        
        }               
    }else{/*Nothing to do*/}

    /* add content if any*/         
    if(payload!= null){
        request.content(new StringContentProvider(payload,"UTF-8"));                    
    }else{/*Nothing to do*/}
    return request;
}
```

Here is my Test case:

```
@Test
public void testcreateRequestWithPayload()  {   

    TestBackend testBackend = new TestBackend(3);
    String url="http://www.google.com";

    Request request= testBackend.createRequest(testBackend.getHttpClient(), url, HTTP_METHOD.PUT, null, "payload", null);   

    assertEquals("payload".length(),(request.getContent().getLength()));    //not enough
}
```

I want to be able to test something like:

```
assertEquals("payload",(request.getContent()));
```

[1]http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.3.v20150827/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/api/Request.html

Comment: Where is `TestBackend` from?

Comment: `TestBackend` is my class that I want to test

Comment: Ok, let me put it another way: I have NO clue at all what your createRequest method actually DOES. So I have no clue where you put your "payload". So how are we supposed to tell you how to get it back? Please post the method where you generate your request.

Comment: oh sorry I see, I edited my question with my method code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you put a `StringContentProvider` there, so that's what you'll get back with getContent(). But actually you don't need to know that, since afaik (not that used to the jetty client) you only need the ContentProvider interface...

```
final ContentProvider provider = request.getContent();
final Iterator<ByteBuffer> it = provider.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    final ByteBuffer next = it.next();
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[next.capacity()];
    next.get( bytes );
    // Should by "payload"
    String content = new String( bytes, Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) );
}
```

(Never used to use ByteBuffer, so perhaps there are some better ways to do that, but you should be able to find documentation for that more easily, since ByteBuffer is standard java and not jetty specific ;-).